# Name that Movie (part deux)

Tags: rebus, knowledge, computer-puzzle

I am writing to inform you that I have constructed another set of clues that will each lead you to a movie title. To make it more interesting, each of the movies has something in common. Whatever that something is leads into the final clue.

1.

```
<h1>hit</h1>
```

2.

```
P227, M4
```

3.

```
iddqd
```

4.

```
A Konami hit performs music
```

Final.

```
Common(1,2,3,4)+FB
```

Hint:

> Just to be even more confusing, the final answer is not a movie.

Hint #2:

> The final answer is the name of something you could have seen in an auditorium.

I'm really not convinced that this is a well-constructed puzzle. One or more clues might be a bit of a stretch. I don't feel good about it. Someone will probably solve it anyway. :/

Comment: Does it have anything to do with Chuck Norris?

Comment: @choz **Everything** has to do with Chuck Norris. :P

Answer (score 9, accepted):

OK, let's have a go. 4 is quite the stretch, but all the other match perfectly (at least in my head).

First the common:

```
Common(1,2,3,4)+FB
```

> The common is **Mark Wahlberg**, <strike>add FaceBook to that and we get Mark Zuckerberg</strike> and the answer is **Marky Mark and the Funky Bunch** (a hip-hop group led my Mark Wahlberg).

Now the clues:

```
<h1>hit</h1>
```

> This will make "hit" big. It will even make it "the biggest", so **The Biggest Hit (1998)**

```
P227, M4
```

> The name of 2 guns, so **2 Guns (2013)**

```
iddqd
```

> A cheat code that will make you invincible in doom, so **Invincible (2006)**

```
A Konami hit performs music
```

> <strike>Now this one will be a stretch... Konami, had this game Guitar Freaks. Later Guitar Heroes popped up. In Guitar Heroes there was this character, who is named Izzy, which is the nickname of the titular character of **Rock Star (2011)**</strike> Thanks to [Cerberus](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/13268/cerberus)'s [answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/16587/5610), this should actually be **Contraband (2012)**, derived from Contra - a Konami game (part of Konami Classics Series: Arcade Hits), and band.

Comment: I knew it had something to do with Mark Wahlberg and eventually Zuckerburg, but couldn't get all the connects.

Comment: So close! Wrong on the final answer, though.

Comment: @IanMacDonald How about now?

Answer (score 3):

In addition to dmg's answer, the fourth clue most likely refers to

> Contraband (2012), Contra+band, of which the cast also includes Mark Wahlberg.

Answer (score 1):

*This is partial answer. As each clue lead to a movie title,* 
First clue says

> Biggest hit, I am not sure about parameters to define biggest hit : So **Avatar(2009)** or **The Big Hit(1998)**

Second clue

> P227, M4 both are guns so, **Guns(1990)** or **2 Guns(2013)**

Third clue

> iddhq is cheat code for shooter game Doom which gives God mode. **Doom(2005)** is also a movie.

Fourth clue

> Movies related to Konami games, **Silent Hill(2006)** or **Teenage Mutant Ninja Turtles(2014)**
> All 4 movies suggest answer is related to war, killing, guns.

Answer (score 0):

*Note that this is just a partial answer...*

The first clue leads to the following:

> The largest hit. In the HTML code `<h1>hit</h1>` `h1` means a header, and it is the largest one.

The fourth clue(not really sure...)

> Konami Digital Entertainment is an Arcade Game Company famous for making games such as YUGIOH! and series such as TMNT. But I do not understand how Konami is related with music.

Edit(for 4):

> A game company and music, what do they have in common? -- Entertainment! This must somehow be related to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

*Another partial answer...*

2.

> [2 Guns](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1272878/). P227 and M4 are both guns.

3.

> [Doom](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0419706/). iddqd is the cheat code to activate God mode in the cult classic game Doom.